# How do I detect players being on a block without pressure plates or tripwires?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I detect players being on a block without pressure plates or tripwires? Preferably with command blocks. This is on *Minecraft: Java Edition*.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version.

1.12 or older use:`/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:stone 0 /say hi`

1.13 or newer use:`execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:stone 0 run say hi`